# Discussing conditions of an offer

Tags: graduate-admissions

I have been made an offer to study for a masters at a top university in London. 
The offer I have been made is quite specific with requirements in individual components of the course. I have accepted the offer.

There is a strong possibility that I may miss the conditions of the offer but only by an extremely small margin and this is obviously causing me much anxiety.

I am thinking of emailing the university and asking them hypothetically what would happen if someone missed the offer by an extremely small margin just so I can start to make preparations.
I was thinking more of emailing the program head to understand what they would usually do in this situation.

My question is, is it a good idea or not?
Could it effect me in a negative way?

Comment: Is this something like a minimum GPA requirement or something like a degree received by requirement or when you must be in residence?

Comment: It is something like a minimum GPA requirement to meet the conditions of the offer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For minimum GPA, there isn't much utility in letting them know ahead of time.

They either have an absolute GPA cutoff or they have some flexibility. If there's an absolute cutoff, then there's not much you can do.

If there's flexibility, then you can try to argue mitigating variables at the point when you have to tell them your final grades. There's not much advantage in starting the argument before you present your grades, and in some ways this may hurt your chances because they might think you should be using your energies right now to try to improve your grades.

In all likelihood, you were accepted with awareness that your grades were weak. In that case, they may want you to go on academic probation or you might have to forgo some scholarships/funding until your grades improve. Not the end of the world.

Comment: I was thinking about not letting them know about me personally. I was planning on asking them hypothetically. The idea was to email them questions to find out more information about the course and the modules they offer i.e  For example on their website it says students may take up to 2 undergraduate modules and I was thinking of asking them would a person be allowed to take more than 2 in any case, for example missing the offer slightly etc...and then at the end just slip them a hypothetical question about their requirements and if someone did not meet them

Comment: What's the point? Either they have leeway or they don't. Bring sneaky doesn't help your case, in fact it hurts it. Do your best with your grades then see what they say.

Comment: Ok, makes sense

Comment: _I was planning on asking them hypothetically._ — Yeah, that _never_ works.